# "Envelope namespace was unexpected" error in .NET WSDL endpoint hosted in Mulesoft

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl, mule

We have a endpoint hosted in Mule that has been migrated from a .NET ASMX web service definition file.

The placement of the namespaces differs between what .NET expects and what Mule appears to have implemented from that WSDL.

The error coming from the .NET client connecting to the endpoint is as follows:

> Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace http://foo/bar/ was
>   unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.

The SOAP envelope that Mule expects looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:foo="http://foo/bar/">
    <soap:Body>
        <foo:DoSomething>
            <foo:xmlDocument>
            </foo:xmlDocument>
        </foo:DoSomething>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Whilst the WSDL hosted in .NET translates the WSDL as:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
      <DoSomething xmlns="http://foo/bar/">
        <xmlDocument></xmlDocument>
      </DoSomething>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The http://foo/bar namespace is attached to the message body in .NET and I'm fairly sure that this conflicting implementation is causing the error when a message is posted from the .NET client to the Mule hosted endpoint.

I am unable to alter the .NET client. It is a third party calling this service, which I have no influence on. I need to alter the Mule endpoint in order for it to accept these messages as they are sent currently.

The original WSDL looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://foo/bar/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://foo/bar/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://foo/bar/">
      <s:element name="DoSomething">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="xmlDocument" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="DoSomethingResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DoSomethingResult" type="s:int" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="DoSomethingSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DoSomething" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DoSomethingSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DoSomethingResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="DoSomethingInboundSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="DoSomething">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:DoSomethingSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:DoSomethingSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="DoSomethingInboundSoap" type="tns:DoSomethingInboundSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="DoSomething">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://foo/bar/DoSomething" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="DoSomethingInboundSoap12" type="tns:DoSomethingInboundSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="DoSomething">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://foo/bar/DoSomething" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="DoSomethingInbound">
    <wsdl:port name="DoSomethingInboundSoap" binding="tns:DoSomethingInboundSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://foo/bar/DoSomethingInbound.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="DoSomethingInboundSoap12" binding="tns:DoSomethingInboundSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://foo/bar/DoSomethingInbound.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: You can't alter the client, but you can alter the WSDL, right? Also, do you need to support both SOAP 1.1 and 1.2?

Comment: I can indeed alter the WSDL hosted in Mule. Ideally both SOAP versions should be supported.

Comment: How about generating instance from your provided wsdl : https://daysincode.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/c-generate-class-from-wsdl-definition.html

Comment: from an experience : generate your stub with `wsimport`. Do not use xjc.

Comment: @Rebecca I am facing the issue while integrating SAP web service in the web API project. Error: `Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ was unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.` M new to this!